# Need help in csv export

Tags: php, csv, yii

I've a strange problem. Actually I am using export csv in yii with ECSVExport. And its working fine. When I export csv then its headers looks something like this.

```
organisation_path, client_key and so on
```

Now I need to add one row before header (I mean above titles). So I used below lines after export csv but before save file to specified location.

```
$handle = fopen($path, 'r+');
fputcsv($handle, array('version', '1'));
fclose($handle);
```

And after adding this in my csv, added a new row like

```
version, 1
```

but my header title became like

```
on_path, client_key and so on
```

So now my problem is when I've added new row at beginning then why my csv title gets disturb (I mean before it was organisation_path but after adding row it became on_path). Is there any better way to add row at beginning of my csv file? Actually I don't want to run any loop here as I just want to add one row before header title.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are overwriting the first 10 characters of your file, so yes, `organisati` will be gone. You should write your version information before you add the contents. However, note that adding a row like that kind-of invalidates your csv file as now any program trying to read it will see only 2 columns.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against prepending version information. Your file is malformed at that point. If you need to indicate a version, do so in the filename, ie `my-file-v1.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening file in `r+` mode means that

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.

So, when you write your version string, current content is overwritten. And you can see that lengths of `version, 1` and `organizati` are the same.

So, you can write your version **before** exporting to file.

Or `file_get_contents()` of your file, prepend this string with your version string and then with `file_put_contents()` write new data to a file.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It worked like a charm. Thank you very much